# What does visceral means in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Some people’s imagery is largely nonvisual: visceral or emotional or
>   kinesthetic or something else.

What does visceral mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I think it refers to the fact that some people's nonvisual "imagery" comes in the form of a gut feeling or reaction, a base sensation that is hard to articulate with words.

Comment: Correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

It means "instinctive", and relates to someone's deep-down feelings.